# Table with fixed header, first column and footer + Scroll inside

Tags: jquery, html, css, html-table

I have to create a table that contains a lot of data. Therefore, need some help finding a solution to how to make it very flexible but do not fill up too much space.

I have thought it should work as shown in the picture here:

[image: Table]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can make class on your part like:

```css
.block {
  display: block;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>...</th>
    <th>...</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>....</td>
    <td class='block'>lot of data</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```